# P-Value in one side ANOVA analysis of summarized groups

Tags: r, statistics, anova, oneway

I have summarized data from four groups (mean, sd, n) and I wanna know if they are signifikant different (pvalue).

I used the "ind.oneway.second(m = m, n = n, sd = sd)" formula of the rpsychi package to calculate ANOVA analysis.
It shows me a lot of helpful data, but not the p-value. Is there any possibilty with the formula above or with another one? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi mira2007, welcome to Stack Overflow. This function isn't designed directly to calculate individual p-values of mean differences. You can get an overall experiment-wise p-value by looking up the p-value of the F statistic using the appropriate degrees of freedom. You can also look at the contrasts to see if any of them do not overlap zero (default alpha is 0.05). However, this function doesn't explicitly calculate p-values.